# jackson jaxb annotation for @XmlEnumValue

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I have an  @XmlEnumValue in a generated class and I want to test a JSON mesage (I will pass in JSON message the value that must be mapped to @XmlEnumValue) and see  if my value is getting mapped. But I am unable to do this.I Solved a similar problem to read @XmlElement by adding below code. Id there any similar approach for supporting @XmlEnumValue also ??? I am looking for such annotaion property name..

```
 <bean id="jaxbAnnotationInspector"
    class="org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector"/>
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnotationInspector"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please see this link for a answer similar to my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935538/jackson-jaxb-annotation-for-xmlenumvalue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're using such configuration to get it working

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    return objectMapper;
}
```